# Numpy tensor: Tensordot over frontal slices of tensor

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to perform a matrix multiplication with frontal slices of a 3D tensor, shown below. If `X.shape == (N, N)`, and `Y.shape == (N, N, Y)`, the resulting tensor should be of shape `(N, N, Y)`.

What's the proper `np.tensordot` syntax to achieve this?

I'm trying to limit myself to `np.tensordot`, and not `np.einsum`, because I want to later translate this solution to Theano. Unfortunately, Theano does not have `np.einsum` implemented yet.

[image]

Graphics adapted from [this paper](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/07070111X) about tensor multiplication.
The non-tensordot answer is equivalent to the following

```
tensor = np.random.rand(3, 3, 2)
X = np.random.rand(3, 3)

output = np.zeros((3, 3, 2))
output[:, :, 0] = X.dot(tensor[:, :, 0])
output[:, :, 1] = X.dot(tensor[:, :, 1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reduction is along `axis=1` for `X` and `axis=0` for `tensor`, thus [`np.tensordot`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html) based solution would be -

```
np.tensordot(X,tensor, axes=([1],[0]))
```

**Explanation :**

Let's take your iterative solution for explanation and in it the first iteration :

```
output[:, :, 0] = X.dot(tensor[:, :, 0])
```

In the dot product, the first input is `X`, whose shape is `(N x N)` and the second input is `tensor[:, :, 0]`, which is the first slice along the last axis and its shape is `(N x N`). That dot product is causing reduction along the second axis of `X`, i.e. `axis=1` and along the first axis, i.e. `axis=0` of `tensor[:, :, 0]`, which also happens to be the first axis of the entire array `tensor`. Now, this continues across all iterations. Therefore, even in the big picture, we need to do the same : Reduce/ Lose `axis=1` in `X` and `axis=0` in tensor, just like we did!

---

Integrating @hlin117's answer

```
np.tensordot(X,tensor, axes=([1],[0]))
```

Timing:

```
>>> N = 200
>>> tensor = np.random.rand(N, N, 30)
>>> X = np.random.rand(N, N)
>>> 
>>> %timeit np.tensordot(X, tensor, axes=([1], [0]))
100 loops, best of 3: 14.7 ms per loop
>>> %timeit np.tensordot(X, tensor, axes=1)
100 loops, best of 3: 15.2 ms per loop
```

Comment: This gives me the exact same answer as above. Thank you!

Comment: One last question, @Divakar. Now I want to accomplish the above using lateral slices, using a `(n, m, m)` tensor. (`output[0, :, :] = X.dot(Tensor[0, :, :])`, etc. I've tried `np.tensor(X, Tensor, axes=([1], [1])`, but this doesn't give me the desired results. What should the `axes` parameter be in this case?

Comment: @hlin117 Because of the way you are storing the output, you need to transpose thereafter : `np.tensordot(X,tensor, axes=([1],[1])).transpose(1,0,2)`.

Comment: Thank you. I would never have guessed that such a transposed would need to be performed. Can you explain why this transformation has to take place?

Comment: @hlin117 Well, let's say `X : (m1,n1)` and `tensor : (m2,n2,r2)`   with `np.tensordot(X,tensor, axes=([1],[1]))`, we are reducing it to `(m1,m2,r2)`. But, because the output is being gathered by iterating along `m2` for `tensor`, we need that as the first axis in the output, so we need to swap `m1` and `m2`, that is swap first two axes with that transpose. Hope that made sense!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the above is equivalent to the following:

```
np.tensordot(X, tensor, axes=1)
```

`axes=1`, because (if the `axes` argument is a scalar) `N` should be the last axis of the first argument, and `N` should be the first axis of the second argument.