# np.dot product between two 3D matrices along specified axis

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication, tensor, numpy-ndarray

I have two 3D matrices:

```
a = np.random.normal(size=[3,2,5])
b = np.random.normal(size=[5,2,3])
```

I want the dot product of each slice along 2 and 0 axes respectively:

```
c = np.zeros([3,3,5]) # c.size is 45
c[:,:,0] = a[:,:,0].dot(b[0,:,:])
c[:,:,1] = a[:,:,1].dot(b[1,:,:])
...
```

I would like to do that using np.tensordot (for efficiency and speed)
I have tried:

```
c = np.tensordot(a, b, axes=[2,0])
```

but I get a 4D array with 36 elements (instead of 45). c.shape, c.size = ((3L, 2L, 2L, 3L), 36). I have found a similar question here ([Numpy tensor: Tensordot over frontal slices of tensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36072042/numpy-tensor-tensordot-over-frontal-slices-of-tensor)) but it's not exactly what I want, and I was unable to extrapolate that solution to my problem.
To summarise, can I use np.tensordot to compute c array show above?

Update #1

The answer by @hpaulj is what I wanted, however in my system (python 2.7 and np 1.13.3) those aproaches are pretty slow:

```
n = 3000
a = np.random.normal(size=[n, 20, 5])
b = np.random.normal(size=[5, 20, n])


t = time.clock()
c_slice = a[:,:,0].dot(b[0,:,:])
print('one slice_x_5: {:.3f} seconds'.format( (time.clock()-t)*5 ))

t = time.clock()
c = np.zeros([n, n, 5])
for i in range(5):
     c[:,:,i] = a[:,:,i].dot(b[i,:,:])
print('for loop: {:.3f} seconds'.format(time.clock()-t))

t = time.clock()
d = np.einsum('abi,ibd->adi', a, b)
print('einsum: {:.3f} seconds'.format(time.clock()-t))

t = time.clock()
e = np.tensordot(a,b,[1,1])
e1 = e.transpose(0,3,1,2)[:,:,np.arange(5),np.arange(5)]
print('tensordot: {:.3f} seconds'.format(time.clock()-t))

a = a.transpose(2,0,1)
t = time.clock()
f = np.matmul(a,b)
print('matmul: {:.3f} seconds'.format(time.clock()-t))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to work with `einsum` than `tensordot`.  So let's start there:

```
In [469]: a = np.random.normal(size=[3,2,5])
     ...: b = np.random.normal(size=[5,2,3])
     ...: 
In [470]: c = np.zeros([3,3,5]) # c.size is 45
In [471]: for i in range(5):
     ...:     c[:,:,i] = a[:,:,i].dot(b[i,:,:])
     ...:     

In [472]: d = np.einsum('abi,ibd->iad', a, b)
In [473]: d.shape
Out[473]: (5, 3, 3)
In [474]: d = np.einsum('abi,ibd->adi', a, b)
In [475]: d.shape
Out[475]: (3, 3, 5)
In [476]: np.allclose(c,d)
Out[476]: True
```

I had to think a bit about to match up the dimensions.  It helped to focus on `a[:,:,i]` as 2d, and similarly for `b[i,:,:]`.  So the `dot` sum is over the middle dimension of both arrays (size 2).

In testing ideas it might help if the first 2 dimensions of `c` were different.  There'd be less chance of mixing them up.

It's easy to specify the `dot` summation axis (axes) in `tensordot`, but harder to constrain the handling of the other dimensions.  That's why you get a 4d array.

I can get it to work with a transpose, followed by taking the diagonal:

```
In [477]: e = np.tensordot(a,b,[1,1])
In [478]: e.shape
Out[478]: (3, 5, 5, 3)
In [479]: e1 = e.transpose(0,3,1,2)[:,:,np.arange(5),np.arange(5)]
In [480]: e1.shape
Out[480]: (3, 3, 5)
In [481]: np.allclose(c,e1)
Out[481]: True
```

I've calculated a lot more values than needed, and thrown most of them away.

`matmul` with some transposing might work better.

```
In [482]: f = a.transpose(2,0,1)@b
In [483]: f.shape
Out[483]: (5, 3, 3)
In [484]: np.allclose(c, f.transpose(1,2,0))
Out[484]: True
```

I  think of the `5` dimension as 'going-along-for-ride'. That's what your loop does.  In `einsum` the `i` is the same in all parts.