# Numpy matrix-wise dot product

Tags: python, numpy

Pardon me for possibly an easy question.

Is there an elegant, numpy way to apply the dot product matrix-wise in tensor?

e.g.

```
import numpy as np
M = np.array(range(12)).reshape(2,2,3)
N = np.array(range(12)).reshape(2,3,2)
```

And then I'll have following result

```
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5]],

        [[ 6,  7,  8],
        [ 9, 10, 11]]])

array([[[ 0,  3],
        [ 1,  4],
        [ 2,  5]],

       [[ 6,  9],
        [ 7, 10],
        [ 8, 11]]])
```

And then I want the matrix-element dot operation,

```
np.dot(M[0], N[0]), np.dot(M[1], N[1])
```

Is there a elegant, numpy way to apply the operation at the same time?

Thanks in advance!

Update #1

I'm sorry I didn't make it clear! I actually want the cross product of the matrix-element of two tensor.

I aim to get an another tensor with the element like

```
result = (M[0].dot(N[0])
          M[1].dot(N[1]))
```

That means if I got a tensor M with shape [L, u, v], and a tensor N with shape [L, v, w]. I hope got the result with shape [L, u, w]. Finally getting the matrix-element cross product operation.

I have found the question

[np.dot product between two 3D matrices along specified axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49281459/np-dot-product-between-two-3d-matrices-along-specified-axis)

but I think that's not the answer I want.

But I found the question

[Numpy elementwise product of 3d array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31957364/numpy-elementwise-product-of-3d-array?noredirect=1&lq=1)

is exactly what I want.

Thanks a lot for @Brenlla, @Divakar, @hpaulj answering.

Comment: Take a look at this for the 2nd part of your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49281459/np-dot-product-between-two-3d-matrices-along-specified-axis

Comment: This one works as long as one of your arrays is only 2D https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36072042/numpy-tensor-tensordot-over-frontal-slices-of-tensor

Comment: @Divakar, your duplicate needs editing to include a newer option: `M@N`.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks! Yes, that was due. Edited.

Comment: Thanks a lot for @Brenlla 's answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for @Divakar 's answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for @hpaulj 's answer.